# Copy rows onto new workbook based on column value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently creating a new workbook on the fly and was wondering how you copy across data if certain conditions are met i.e. in this case if Primary Contact = John and Primary Device = Desktop then copy across the ID, First Name, Last Name and Email columns into the new workbook that was just created under column/row *A11 onwards, B11 onwards, C11 onwards, D11 onwards* (depending on how much data is pulled). Is this possible?

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
Sub NewWb()

' Create new workbook with a pre-defined name
Workbooks.Add
NewBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Workbooks(NewBook).Activate

' Set bg to white
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 2

' Sanity test
'MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(3, 3).Value)
'MsgBox (ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, 1).Value)

' Get last row
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Pull out relevant data from master spreadsheet where column F = "John"
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A2:Z2").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="John"
    ' Copy and paste NBK
    .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range ("A11")
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: How much stuff do you need to do with your data? Are you hard coding in the search values, or will they be dynamically pulled from some other list? If you are just searching for a single name + computer, you could simply use a worksheet function (if A1 = "John" and B1 = "Desktop", 1 else 0), and loop through copying each value set to an array or worksheet. You can implement the same thing by manually looping through the range and simply transferring the values across. What are your requirements (e.g. what should the end product look like and why?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figurd it out!

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A2:Z2").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="John"
    .Range("A2:Z2").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="Desktop"
    ' Copy and paste NBK, first name, last name
    .Range("A3:C" & LastRow).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & NextHeaderRow + 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    ' Copy and paste email
    .Range("E3:E" & LastRow).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & NextHeaderRow + 5).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```